# Filters/Decision Splits for specific rows in a Data Extension (when Contact/Subscriber has more than one row)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, filters, contactbuilder

When a Contact/Subscriber has multiple rows in a Data Extension, I need to be able to filter and make decisions based on a specific row (i.e., the row that qualified them for the current entry into the Journey).

All our Journey entry sources are Data Extensions, populated & updated (hourly) via SQL Query from synchronized Salesforce records.  I created an Attribute Group with a "one-to-many" relationship between the MC Subscriber Key and ContactID in the data extensions.

In the sample below, I want to exit a Contact from a Journey if their HearingStatus = "Completed".  But I want to keep this Contact in the Journey because **Row 2** on the data extension is what is current and qualified them for re-entry.

- Filtering using Journey/Entry data does not work, because the values can change during the life of the Journey.
- Filtering using the Contact Data --> Attribute Group does not work, because it treats all rows for the ContactID the same, and if a Contact enters a Journey more than once the decision split might look at the first row instead of the second/current row.

[image]

How can I force a reference to a specific DE row in Filters, Decision Splits, and Goals?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HearingID appears to be the specific row identifier you want to query in your splits. When you configure the decision split you can use an attribute comparison on the Contact Data with your Journey Data. This is a checkbox in filter criteria builder that allows you to drag and drop another field in your data model to compare to.

So essentially your split criteria would be an attribute comparison on the Contact Data field HearingID with the Journey Data field value of HearingID AND whatever HearingStatus you want to query for.

This will result in a decision split only on the HearingStatus of the row where the Contact Data HearingID matches the HearingID in your Journey Data.