# Journey entry on Opportunity Contact Role

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, entry-criteria

In a project I need to enter contacts into a SFMC Journey when there's a new opportunity. The association between Contact and Opportunity happens through the Object Opportunity Contact Role (Junction Object).

So my approach would be to create a Salesforce Journey Entry Event based on the creation of a Opportunity Contact Role record, which is ideal because it directly lookups to both Contact and Opportunity.

However, I **cannot select Opportunity Contact Role** as object for my Journey entry.

**Does someone know the reason for this and if this can be "activated"?**

- I can see the object in Contact Builder > Synchronized Data Sources
- I can also see the ContactId field in the available fields list (needed for
  the sendable Contact association)
- This behaviour occurs in different SFMC accounts of other projects. So it doesn't appear to be a "freak" configuration
- Other objects of the same relationship type (eg campaign members, visitreport contacts) can be used without issue. Even those where multiple (junction) associations can be created for the same contact. I tested this on the visitreport contact object.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Contacts to Opportunities are not available in Journey Builder as a Journey Entry Source because of the One-to-Many relationship. A contact can have multiple opportunities. See relevant questions here: [Journey Builder and Decision Splits with Contact Data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258317/journey-builder-and-decision-splits-with-contact-data/258333#258333).

Your best bet is to query the synchronized data extension to inject into your journey.

I don't see Opportunity Contact as well but my SalesCloud is set up as Person Accounts:

[image: Opportunity with Person Accounts]

Comment: On Opportunities I agree. But it appears unlikely on the Opportunity Contact Role with a direct lookup to the contact. Campaign Membership records are a similar construction and there it works. The same for custom Junction objects. I tried it with a custom junction object that can be assigned multiple times to the same records on both sides (like the Opportunity Contact Role).

Comment: I tested against the assumption in my comment and can confirm it. It is not an issue of one to many relationship. I updated this in my question

Comment: Thanks Stephan. I looked in my dev account and see that I can access but with PersonAccount set up. Sorry I do not see Contacts. Edited my post to include the screenshot.

Comment: The direct relation between the opportunity object and contacts only exists for PersonAccounts as those have a 1:1 relationship between accounts, removing the need to add multiple contacts of the same account to an opportunity. If you look at the sync object step in contact builder you can search for "Opportunity Contact Role". This is the object I need. When you select it and look at the fields you will see the standard ContactId lookup field that normally allows usage for journey entry source. Unfortunately I can't provide a screenshot at the moment.